# Moving through list starting at both ends and stopping at middle using iterators

Tags: c++, list, loops, iterator

I'm trying to make a while loop for some code that has two iterators, one that starts at the beginning of the list, and is incremented and another that started at the end and is decremented, wanting them to stop once the middle of the list is reached and the whole list has been covered. When doing a similar thing with vector iterators I was able to just do  `while (limit > first)`, but this doesn't work and gives a compiler error when done with list iterators. I'm working on a book problem that has a task requirement of not allocating any new memory in the code aside from the two given iterators and am having trouble figuring out how to move through the elements of the list properly.

Comment: See `std::distance` for calculating the midpoint or where you want to stop.  You can then create an iterator to this location by adding the calculated distance to the `begin` iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse iterators dereference to the prior element than the one they internally refer to (the "base"). (See [this image](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) for a visual explanation.)

What this means is that if you have:

```
auto forward = a_list.begin();
auto backward = a_list.rbegin();
```

And you increment `forward` and `backward` alternately, there will be a time when `forward == backward.base()`.  You must test this after incrementing *each* iterator, *not both* otherwise they could cross each other before you test them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [std::list::size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size):

```
#include <list>
using namespace std;

void handle(int v) { cout << v << endl; }
void main() {
    list<int> l = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    auto f = l.cbegin();
    auto r = l.crbegin();
    const int stepsCount = l.size() / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < stepsCount; ++i) {
        handle(*f); handle(*r);
        f++; r++;
    }
    if (l.size() % 2) handle(*r);
}
```